# Selenium returning the incorrect number of elements

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm attempting to use selinium to count the number of rows in a table. My current implimentation is

```
table = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id"]')

print(len(table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')))
```

on the following table

```
<table class="grid" id="id">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="header-row"> </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdclass"> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td class="tdclass"> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdclass"> </td> 
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The direct access to the tbody [If that helps] is

```
/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody
```

My output whe  running this code is as follows

```
>>> print(len(table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')))
28
```

My expected output is

```
>>> print(len(table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')))
4
```

Now, the thing that I find strange, is `print(len(table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')))` returns 28 every time. Whether I add or remove table rows, 28 will always be returned.

I assume I'm just being very silly, and in fact the solution is right in front of me, but I just don't see it.

Comment: `Main_ctl00_gridList` is correct `id` of table or `id`? `<table class="grid" id="id">` or `<table class="grid" id="Main_ctl00_gridList">`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited for Stackoverflow but forgot to change the id. Editied post.

Comment: Try `print(len(self.driver.find_elements_by_id('id')))` to check if there are more tables with the same `@id` - you might handle wrong (hidden) table with 28 rows...

Comment: Just ran your suggestion, it returns 1. Rather confusing

Comment: if you don't mind post full html or url.

Comment: Unfortunately not a possibility to post the source code @ewwink, I will edit and post a modified version.

Comment: sure you don't have to post original code

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I needed to wait for the page to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the webpage I am dealing with uses AJAX, I needed to call time.sleep(x).

See below

```
    >>> self.driver.find_element_by_name(x).send_keys(xkeys)
    >>> self.driver.find_element_by_name(y).click()
    >>> time.sleep(5)
    >>> table = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id"]')
    >>> print(len(table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')))
```

returns 4.